# Navigation menu in Laravel child view dynamically setting HTTP routes

Tags: html, rest, laravel

In my Laravel 5.2 CRUD app, the navigation menu is inside of its own layout which each child view inherits.

However, for one of the child views (create.blade.php), which is reached via its RESTful resource controller, every link on the navigation menu is changed.

E.g. The HOME link says **mywebsite.dev/home** when I am on the home page and the **mywebsite.dev/books** page.

However, when I got to **mywebsite.dev/books/create**, all the navigation items now have **mywebsite.com/books/** before them. So e.g. the About page, when clicked from the Create New Book page, goes to **mywebsite.dev/books/about**, instead of going to **mywebsite.dev/books**. Funnily enough, only the link to BOOKS page is correct and says **mywebsite.dev/books**

In my navigation, the HOME, BOOKS, and ABOUT pages are listed as href="/" href="/books "and href="/about"

Any ideas why it is so?

EDIT:
My BooksController:

```
 public function index()
{
    // get all the books
    $books = Book::all();

    // load the view and pass the books
    return View::make('books.index')->with('books',$books);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return View::make('books.create');
}
```

Here is the routes.php:

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::resource('books','BookController');
```

Comment: post your current `routes.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `url()` helper in your views. So it assures you that you get an absolute link.

```
<a href="{{ url('/about') }}">About</a>
<a href="{{ url('/books') }}">Books</a>
<a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
```